# Kernel freezes when running federated computation with tensorflow_federated and nest_asyncio

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, tensorflow-federated, nest-asyncio

I try to run a simple federated computation using tensorflow_federated.
tff.federated_computation() -> after running this, the kernel freezes and am not able to run other cells.

TF-Federated needs asyncio to prevent [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/842) error.

My code is available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/869).

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by downgrading the jupyter notebook and tornado version.

Default versions of notebook >= 6.x and tornado >= 6.0

By running the command,

> pip install jupyter notebook==5.7.8 tornado==4.5.0

This issue is fixed